# Searching a string for 'good' without using the string.h library

Tags: c, string

C Programming Language. The problem is focused on functions and recursion. The problem is just to check if the line contains 'good', regardless of capitalization. It compiles and matches the sample output but the checking software marks it incorrect.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

int checkString(char string[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i<80; i++)
    {
        if(string[i] == 103 || string[i] == 71 && string[i+1] == 111 || string[i+1] == 79 && string[i+2] == 111 || string[i+1] == 79 && string[i+3] == 100 || string[i+1] == 68)
        {
            return 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int goodCheck()
{
    char string[80] = {'0'};
    fgets(string, 80, stdin);
    if(checkString(string)==1)
        {
            return 3;
        }
    else 
        {
            return 0;
        }
}

int main()
{
    int cases = 0;
    char string[80];
    scanf("%d", &cases);
    fflush(stdin);  
    for(int i = 1; i<=cases; i++)
    {
        if (goodCheck() == 3)
        {
            printf("Case #%d: yes\n", i);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Case #%d: no\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
This is the code post revisions, though it is still marked wrong it is graded better than before.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

int checkString(char string[]);

void goodCheck(int i);

int main()
{
    int cases = 0;
    char string[80];
    scanf("%d\n", &cases);
    for(int i = 1; i<=cases; i++)
    {
        goodCheck(i);
    }   
}

int checkString(char string[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i<80; i++)
    {
        if((string[i] == 'g' || string[i] == 'G') && 
        (string[i+1] == 'o' || string[i+1] == 'O') && 
        (string[i+2] == 'o' || string[i+2] == 'O') && 
        (string[i+3] == 'd' || string[i+3] == 'D'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    }
}

void goodCheck(int i)
{
    char string[80] = {'0'};
    fgets(string, 80, stdin);
    if(checkString(string)==1)
    {
        printf("Case #%d: yes\n", i);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Case #%d: no\n", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you by `103` mean the (ASCII) encoded value of `'g'` then say `'g'` instead. Also, don't forget that C `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings. You never check for the terminator anywhere, and you *will* go out of bounds trying to find the "string" you're looking for.

Comment: Operator precedence, `&&` is higher in the hierarchy than `||`. So for the if, you would need to write `(...=='g' || ...=='G') && (...=='o' || ...=='O') && ...`. The current variant matches a lot more than a case-insensitive 'good'. Btw: instead of the numbers, you can use the letters in single quotes as shown.

Comment: Oh, and `fflush` on an input-only stream (like `stdin`) is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Even though some systems implement it as an *extension* of the language, it's not portable and you should avoid it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude fun fact: it will not go beyond, as the terminator character does not match with the letter and short-circuit evaluation stops then. (But yes, it is another thing if someone uses it by luck, or actually knows what happens)

Comment: @tevemadar Actually, considering that the OP doesn't check for the terminator, the loop will go beyond the end of the string, where there might be data corresponding to the values being compared to, so the OP could indeed go out of bounds. ***Could*** instead of *will*.

Comment: Furthermore, if the "string" is not found, what do you return then? Not returning anything from a function declared to return a value, and using that (un)returned value will *also* lead to undefined behavior. If your compiler doesn't should at you for at least that, then you need to enable more warnings, and treat them as errors.

Comment: Finally some nitpicking: The `return` statement returns *immediately*. Statements after it will not be executed. That means your `break` is useless.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback, I have posted a revised version of my code. Got rid of `fflush(stdin)` and corrected the requirements along with removing the `break` statement.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, that is true. I was thinking about addressing outside the buffer, not the string.

Comment: Hint: (deterministic) Finite State Machine.

Answer (score 0):

&& has higher operator precedence than ||. So your code is checking

```
   string[i] == 'g'
|| (string [i] == 'G' && string [i+1] == 'o')
|| (string [i+1] == 'O' && string [i+2] == 'o')
|| (string [i+2] == 'O' && string [i+3] == 'd')
|| string [i+3] == 'D'
```

All substrings starting with "g", or starting with "Go", or containing "Oo" or "Od", or ending with "D", will pass your check. Like "Goofy" will pass, or "Oh my god!".

All variations of "good" do pass, but many incorrect strings pass as well. It seems you haven't tested this with any strings that contain a few, but not all characters of "good". Even "Lady Gaga passes the test" passes the test (because of a single lowercase g).

Answer (score 0):

String searching problems can be solved by finite automata:

---

```
int checkString(char *string)
{
int pos,state;

for(pos=state=0; string[pos]; pos++) {
        switch(string[pos]) {
        case 'G':
        case 'g': if (state++ == 0) continue;
                break;
        case 'O':
        case 'o': if (state++ == 1 || state == 3) continue;
                break;
        case 'D':
        case 'd': if (state == 3) return pos-state; // Got it!
        default:break;
                }
        state=0;
        }
return -1; // Failed
}
```

---